# How to prevent iframe virus? What are all the measures can be taken once affected by it?

Tags: wordpress, security, iframe

Suddenly, I see some of my blog files(wordpress) contains some `<iframe>` tags with links to some websites. How does it happen? What do I have to do to remove this virus and clean my website?

I opened few files using a text editor and removed the `<iframe>` code. Also, changed all my FTP password. How can I ensure that my site is clean now? What are all the preventions I can take to avoid this in futre?

Comment: I could not add iframe,virus and blog tags since I don't have efficient reputation. Sorry, if the tags are wrong.

Comment: I added you iframe, blog and virus are redundant since there is wordpress and security already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cleaning a WordPress install, or any site, of such files is generally straightforward. If there's a pattern, do a search of the relevant files and then replace the bad code.

In the case of WordPress, there are a few different sources of bad code (probably others):

1. An already infected theme was installed
2. Your site's FTP password was guessed and hacked
3. WordPress is insecure and allowed a worm to be installed

One thing you can do is install [TAC (Theme Authenticity Checker)](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tac/), which will scan for the bad stuff.

See [**Hardening WordPress**](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) for steps to take to make WordPress more secure. But basically when I've seen this happen what I do is back everything up (database and all files), then blow that install away and install a fresh WordPress install, fresh replacement plugins, and a fresh theme (if your theme was custom, get rid of the bad code first!).

Googling for "wordpress infection" should get you other articles with similar advice.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, always make sure you have the latest version of Wordpress installed. The admin panel tells you when WP needs updating. If you don't log in too often, you could follow the wordpress.org blog feed to keep on top it.

Every time you download a new theme you should search through the source code for any use of `base64_decode` or `eval` (Notepad++ makes this easy), this is the primary way to hide malicious code or spammy links. You can copy the encoded HTML/PHP into an online [base64 decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) if you like, to see what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on a shared server?

I've previously seen on shared servers instances where one account has been hacked and it's been possible for the hackers to access other sites on the shared server through files which the PHP users has access to.

Comment: If this is the case, you should get your host to use PHP's "safe mode" which protects against this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, Loftx. It's a shared server. How can I prevent these kind of attacks?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat How can I check whether it's is safe mode or not?

Comment: @San: If safe mode is enabled then `ini_get('safe_mode')` will return true. You could also try one of these functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php

Comment: Also note that safe mode has been removed as of PHP 5.3 so in that case your host will have to do something else to restrict access.

Answer (score 0):

or you could just do an in-file search and replace of your folders. Because iframes are evil by default...

Comment: How can I do that? Is there any tool available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Secure Wordpress" plugin which at the beginning was developed by Frank Bueltge. Now sitesecuritymonitor.com maintains it. The plugin contains a method to scan your Wordpress blog against known Vulnerabilities.

See: http://www.sitesecuritymonitor.com/secure-wordpress-plugin